# VoiceXML for Browser?

Tags: text-to-speech, voicexml

I am new to VoiceXML. I have read the documentation and know how it is structured, but wanted to know if it was only for IVR phone systems? Is it possible to use VoiceXML for dialogue managers inside a web application and not through the phone? For example, if I have a function in my web application which allows users to ask questions and start dialogue that can be used as an  answering system, but I also want users to be able to talk to it via a microphone, how can I use VoiceXML?

Answer (score 1):

[Opera supported a flavor of X+V that combined VoiceXML and HTML](http://www.voicexml.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/static/Review/Mar2006/features/multimodal_opera.html).  I never tried it so I can't provide much information on it.

[JVoiceXML](http://jvoicexml.sourceforge.net/) is a very functional VoiceXML browser with multiple front ends.  It didn't have any integrations into speech recognition engines the last time I explored it.

In general, if you want to work with VoiceXML, you are likely going to be working with one of the telephony products and not a web browser.  There are a variety of hosted service providers.  Some, might offer free development access.